# Non-orientable $6$-manifold with $H_4(M)=\mathbb{Z}/2$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Does there exist a smooth, closed, non-orientable $6$-manifold $M$ such that $H_4(M;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2$?

Comment: How about $S^2\times RP^2\times RP^2?$

Comment: I am curious to know if the existence of some manifold like this is meant to be an obstruction for existence of some specific class in bordism groups of immersions, and if so then what is it?!?

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole: Thanks, I think it works!

Comment: @user51223: This question came up when studying mod 2 cohomology classes realizable by immersions/embeddings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$M=S^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2\times\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Since $Tor(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2$, the Künneth formula tells you that the homology is:

- $H_0(M,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$
- $H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$
- $H_2(M,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus \mathbb{Z}$
- $H_3(M,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$
- $H_4(M,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2$
- $H_5(M,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2$
- $H_6(M,\mathbb{Z})=0$.